# Can not initialize external memory chip

Tags: data-structures, initialization, stm32

I have an STM32F103C8T6 uC and an ASIC chip. They communicate with SPI interface, ST being the Master device. On the uC lies a Firmware by the vendor of the ASIC device. I have been trying to shape it to my hardware and development tools. This is the initialization code,

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* init application data                                                 */
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
memset( &sDpAppl, 0, sizeof( sDpAppl ) );
```

and some function declarations,

```
#if VPC3_SERIAL_MODE
//I have already defined these externs
extern void                Vpc3Write      ( VPC3_ADR wAddress, uint8_t bData 
);

extern uint8_t   Vpc3Read    ( VPC3_ADR wAddress );

extern void      Vpc3MemSet ( VPC3_ADR wAddress, uint8_t bValue, uint16_t
                              wLength);

extern uint8_t   Vpc3MemCmp ( VPC3_UNSIGNED8_PTR pToVpc3Memory1, 
                 VPC3_UNSIGNED8_PTR pToVpc3Memory2, uint16_t wLength );

extern void      CopyToVpc3 ( VPC3_UNSIGNED8_PTR pToVpc3Memory, 
                 MEM_UNSIGNED8_PTR pLocalMemory, uint16_t wLength );

extern void      CopyFromVpc3( MEM_UNSIGNED8_PTR pLocalMemory, 
                 VPC3_UNSIGNED8_PTR pToVpc3Memory, uint16_t wLength );

#define CopyToVpc3_( _pToVpc3Memory, _pLocalMemory, _wLength )\
           CopyToVpc3( _pToVpc3Memory, _pLocalMemory, _wLength )

#define CopyFromVpc3_( _pLocalMemory, _pToVpc3Memory, _wLength )\
           CopyFromVpc3( _pLocalMemory, _pToVpc3Memory, _wLength )

#define Vpc3MemSet_( _pToVpc3Memory, _bValue, _wLength )\
           Vpc3MemSet( _pToVpc3Memory, _bValue, _wLength )

#define Vpc3MemCmp_( _pToVpc3Memory1, _pToVpc3Memory2, _wLength )\
           Vpc3MemCmp( _pToVpc3Memory1, _pToVpc3Memory2, _wLength )

#else

#define CopyToVpc3_( _pToVpc3Memory, _pLocalMemory, _wLength )\
           memcpy( _pToVpc3Memory, _pLocalMemory, _wLength )

#define CopyFromVpc3_( _pLocalMemory, _pToVpc3Memory, _wLength )\
           memcpy( _pLocalMemory, _pToVpc3Memory, _wLength )

#define Vpc3MemSet_( _pToVpc3Memory, _bValue, _wLength )\
           memset( _pToVpc3Memory, _bValue, _wLength )

#define Vpc3MemCmp_( _pToVpc3Memory1, _pToVpc3Memory2, _wLength )\
           memcmp( _pToVpc3Memory1, _pToVpc3Memory2, _wLength )

#endif /* #if VPC3_SERIAL_MODE */
```

I'm mostly concerned about the memset() function. In my opinion the  function should initialize the ASIC chip, but to me it seems it doesnt. I am a little confused about it, or what to. I hope some more experienced eye can see what I dont.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please define "initialize"?

Comment: It's not clear how a header file is going to help you solve the problem here.

Comment: Sorry, I meant by initialization, that the memory of the external ASIC chip should be initialized according to defined structures. For example the one, whose address is passed to the memset function.